# Determining relative location of a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a jQuery plugin that consists of a main js file that will load several other js files.  I want to be able to put all the files into a 'myPlugin' folder, and have the main js file find the other scripts no matter what the location of the page that imports the main file.

`location.pathname` will get me the path of the page that loads the plugin, but how do I tell the plugin to load something relative to its own location?

In the following example, I want `myPlugin.js` to find `required1.js` whether it's loaded from `pageA` or `pageB`:

```
pageA.html
/../pageB.html

myPlugin/
  -myPlugin.js (How does `myPlugin.js` find `required1.js`?)
  -required1.js
  -required2.js
```

Thanks...

Comment: It would be much simple if you would use the absolute path instead of the relative path.

Comment: @Henrik- There's no way to know ahead of time the absolute location of where a plugin will be installed.

Comment: Good question. You should also look into script loaders like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) that do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to try to find the reference to myPlugin.js in the DOM of the including page:

```
$('script[src$="myPlugin.js"]').attr("src").replace(/myPlugin\.js$/, 'required1.js')
```

This is hacky, though, and prone to error. I would only use it if a zero-conf solution is absolutely necessary. Otherwise, I would just have the user configure the plugin so it knows where to find its other files.

Comment: That should work for this case. A more generic solution is to [find the last script tag in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203079/get-url-for-currently-executing-javasript/2203207#2203207) (which under normal circumstances will be the one pointing to the currently executing script).