# How do I get to the root directory of an asp.net website? or go back a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have this code and the page resides in /archive/filename
But the popup window when something is clicked is in the root destination of the website not the page. How do I go back one directory or point to the overall root directory?

```
        var popup = window.open("OPC_RRNew.aspx?Id=" + id, "Dialog", options);
```

Ive tried adding a ~ before but it still comes out as /archive/~/OPC_RRNew.aspx?Id=

Comment: Server.MapPath("~");

Comment: JavaScript doesn't know about the `~` syntax. You'd need to preprocess it on the server to generate the right URL. Or if you're confident that it will always be one directory up, you can do `../` or if you're confident that it will always be in the same location relative to the root you can use `/`

Comment: @mason you should just post that as an answer (unless you found duplicate already)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [~/ equivalent in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893144/equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: @mason thank you the ../ worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used ../(filename) to get one directory back.