# I can't navigate from page in one folder to another as new page

Tags: asp.net

[image: I want to navigate from VacancyDetails to JPHome as new page.]I have two folders with web pages of their own. On clicking button on one webform of Recruitment folder I wanted to navigate to web page of JobPortal folder webform as new page.

Navigation within same folder is succeeded but while navigating to page of new folder, the link got the current folder name also which is unwanted so there arouse error.

Response.Write("window.open('JobPortal/JPHome.aspx','_blank')");

i have tried that and what i got after firing the event from recruitment webform is

'Recruitment/JobPortal/JPHome.aspx'

but i want to navigate to 'JobPortal/JPHome.aspx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code as below

```
Response.Write("window.open('../JobPortal/JPHome.aspx','_blank')");
```

First you need to go one folder above using `../` 
And then to folder `JobPortal/`
And then to page `JPHome.aspx`

Or you can use the absolute path in your code.

Comment: Is there difference between '~/' and '../'?
I have tried '~/' it didn't worked so removed it. hadn't think about '../' 
it worked.

Comment: One is C# specific `~/` and the other can be used any where. [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893144/equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: it is not getting processed it is just string in double quotes. You can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874636/what-is-the-difference-between-resolveurl-and-resolveclienturl) it will help you.